# Use HTTP instead of AJP in apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, websocket, ajp

I just added WebSocket support to my spring application. and i have issue with `apache` server config. before WebSocket support, i used `AJP` and everything worked fine:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://192.168.110.60:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://192.168.110.60:8009/
```

And in tomcat's `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" 
           redirectPort="443" maxThreads="2000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Now for WebSocket:

As WebSocket is not support via `AJP`, i used `HTTP`:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

ProxyPass /app/ws ws://192.168.110.60:6332/app/ws
ProxyPassReverse /app/ws ws://192.168.110.60:6332/app/ws

ProxyPass / http://192.168.110.60:6332/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.110.60:6332/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^keep-alive,\ Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://192.168.110.60:6332%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

And in tomcat's `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="6332" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="30000" redirectPort="443" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxThreads="2000"/>
```

With this configs WebSocket works fine, but other requests:

- Asynchronous requests: Sometimes works(!), but sometimes throws `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.
- Synchronous requests: Sometimes works(!), but sometimes throw `Failed to execute 'send' error on 'XMLHttpRequest'` because of `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

**Note:**

- Synchronous/Asynchronous requests work fine without `apache` (only tomcat).
- Synchronous/Asynchronous requests work fine via `AJP`.

Is there any config which i missed to pass requests vai `HTTP` in `apache`?

**UPDATE 1:**

I've find out that the `HOST` header is not set correctly by `apache`, sometimes with `domain:443` but sometimes `domain` (without port)!!

**UPDATE 2:**

By removing these lines, all requests work fine, except WebSocket ones:

```
ProxyPass /app/ws ws://192.168.110.60:6332/app/ws
ProxyPassReverse /app/ws ws://192.168.110.60:6332/app/ws
```

Comment: Lots going on, here. WebSocket `!=` HTTP, so your proxy configuration must be more complicated. Will all WebSocket requests all start with `/app/ws`? If so, config looks okay there. Are you sure you need `Rewrite` at all, here?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Yes I have not any issue with WebSocket requests. Without `Rewrite` WebSocket won't work.

Comment: Something doesn't sound right, there. WebSocket connections *always* begin as HTTP requests which are upgraded. The initial HTTP request does not require any special configuration (other than `ProxyPass`) and further communication will not be performed via HTTP, so the `Rewrite` rules will not apply. I have not wet up WebSockets myself via `httpd` but `ProxyPass` and the proper modules enabled should be sufficient. See e.g. http://notmyitblog.blogspot.com/2014/03/websockets-support-for-apache-httpd.html which uses only `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` to enable WebSocket.